# View state remains the same when a new ViewModel instance is created MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm sure the answer to this is already out there just can't seem to find it. I have a SubView which I am dynamically in the the MainViewModel. This is then displayed to the user using a style. When I create a new instance of the SubViewModel the View is not recreated if it of the same type as it was before. This is an issue as the selected tab remains the same and is not reset to the first tab. Although I could just save the selected tab index in the ViewModel to reset it I feel it is purely View state and should not exist in the ViewModel. I assume this is the styling not noticing that the instance has changed. Is there anyway to force the View to create a new instance every time the ViewModel changes?

Style:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubViewModel}">
    <v:SubView />
</DataTemplate>
```

MainViewModel:

```
if (DisplayItemControl != null)
{
    DisplayItemControl.Cleanup();
    DisplayItemControl = null;
}
DisplayItemControl = new SubViewModel();
```

Comment: Highly recommend you have a look at Caliburn Micro as it makes composition of ViewModels very easy.

Comment: You don't appear to be setting the datacontext anywhere, where is the rest of your code? Where are your bindings? In MVVM, your View Model does not know about your view, and it shouldn't be referencing control names.

Comment: The DataContext is set using a contentcontrol in the view and the style linking a ViewModel to the View. Accompanying line from MainView `<ContentControl Content="{Binding DisplayItemControl}"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `x:Shared="false"` to your **DataTemplate** resource should allow a new instance to be created. This does not work when `DisplayItemControl` is directly set to its new value, instead of setting it to null first, so I've noticed.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubViewModel}" x:Shared="false">
    <v:SubView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what I was looking for. Knew it would probably be an easy fix. Thank you