# MVVM navigation - View instance persists although DataTemplate has x:Shared="False"

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been searching for an answer to my problem, but no luck so far. 
I am new to MVVM but am taking my chances with an app that will be put to work.

The Navigation is implemented by a Menu-Command bound to a RelayCommand /Action reacting to the CommandParameter. This switches the CurrentViewModel in the MainWindowViewModel. The MainWindow has a ContentControl with its content bound to the CurrentViewModel. The Views called this way are all UserControls which are instantiated via DataTemplate.

```
 <DataTemplate  x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type vm:NewViewModel}">
    <local:NewView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

When a View is called up by the Menu, it works just fine. Clicking the same Menu again creates new instance of the viewmodel, but the view does not change (old values still there). 
There aren't too many posts to be found about this Problem as it seems to  hinge on not sharing the view-instance by setting x:shared to false. As stated, this is not working for me. I have also tried [setting the CurrentViewModel to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119077/view-state-remains-the-same-when-a-new-viewmodel-instance-is-created-mvvm)
before it is changed.

I'm problably missing an obvious solution. Would be greatfull for the help anyway.

Here's the code: (the  case:"Correct" is not working)

```
    private InvoiceViewModel _InvoiceViewModel = new InvoiceViewModel();
    private ProductsViewModel _ProductsViewModel = new ProductsViewModel();
    private PrintViewModel _PrintViewModel = new PrintViewModel();
    private CorrectInvoiceViewModel _CorrectInvoiceViewModel = new CorrectInvoiceViewModel();
    private RetouchInvoiceViewModel _RetouchInvoiceViewModel = new RetouchInvoiceViewModel();
    private CorrectionChainViewModel _CorrectionChainViewModel = new CorrectionChainViewModel();
    private RecipientsViewModel _RecipientsViewModel = new RecipientsViewModel();
    private AdjustmentsViewModel _AdjustmentsViewModel = new AdjustmentsViewModel();



    private ViewModelBase _CurrentViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel { get { return _CurrentViewModel; } set { SetProperty(ref _CurrentViewModel, value);} }

    private void OnMenuItemClick(string destination)
    {
        switch (destination)
        {
            case "Invoice":
                CurrentViewModel = _InvoiceViewModel;
                ViewModelTitle = "Neue Rechnung";
                break;

            case "Products":
                CurrentViewModel = _ProductsViewModel;
                ViewModelTitle = "Produkte bearbeiten";
                break;

            case "Correct":
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = null;
                    CurrentViewModel = new CorrectInvoiceViewModel();

                    ViewModelTitle = "Rechnungskorrektur";
                    break;
                }
            case "Retouch":
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = _RetouchInvoiceViewModel;
                    ViewModelTitle = "Retusche";
                    break;
                }
            case "CorrectionChain":
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = _CorrectionChainViewModel;
                    ViewModelTitle = "Rechnungsansicht und Korrekturreihe";
                    break;
                }
            case "Recipients":
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = _RecipientsViewModel;
                    ViewModelTitle = "Empfänger bearbeiten";
                    break;
                }
            case "Adjustments":
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = _AdjustmentsViewModel;
                    ViewModelTitle = "Adressfeld anpassen";
                    break;
                }
            default:
                CurrentViewModel = null;
                break;
        }
    }
```

and the xaml:

```
    <Controls:MetroWindow x:Name="wdw_Main" x:Class="PraxMat_View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PraxMat_View"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:viewmod="clr-namespace:PraxMat_ViewModel;assembly=PraxMat_ViewModel"
    DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel_Resource}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PraxMat" Height="800" Width="1200" WindowTitleBrush="#FF2D2D30"  TitleCaps="False" Icon="images/PraxMat_Logo.png"  Background="Black"  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Grey04}" BorderThickness="1">
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type viewmod:InvoiceViewModel}">
        <local:InvoiceView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate  x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type viewmod:ProductsViewModel}">
        <local:ProductsView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate  x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type viewmod:PrintViewModel}">
        <local:PrintView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Shared="False"  DataType="{x:Type viewmod:CorrectInvoiceViewModel}">
        <local:CorrectInvoiceView/>
    </DataTemplate>


    <DataTemplate x:Shared="False"  DataType="{x:Type viewmod:RetouchInvoiceViewModel}">
        <local:RetouchInvoiceView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate  x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type viewmod:CorrectionChainViewModel}">
        <local:CorrectionChainView DataContext="{StaticResource CorrectInvoiceViewModel_Resource}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate  x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type viewmod:RecipientsViewModel}">
        <local:RecipientsView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate  x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type viewmod:AdjustmentsViewModel}">
        <local:AdjustmentsView/>
    </DataTemplate>


</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="grd_Main" Opacity="{Binding Opacity}">

    <Menu x:Name="men_Main" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Background="#FF1E1E1E" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Grey07}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">

        <MenuItem Header="Menu" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Margin="26,3,0,0" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" Width="100" Padding="6,2,6,4">
            <MenuItem x:Name="mui_Invoice" Header="Neue Rechnung" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25"  Padding="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="Invoice" Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="mui_AlterInvoice" Header="Rechnung anpassen" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu_PopupRight}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25" Padding="5,0,0,0">
                <MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
                <MenuItem x:Name="mui_CorrectInvoice" Header="Korrektur" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25" Padding="0" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="Correct" Margin="0,-4,0,0" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="mui_RetouchInvoice" Header="Retusche" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25" Padding="0" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="Retouch" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="mui_CorrectionChain" Header="Ansicht/Korrekturreihe" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25" Padding="0" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="CorrectionChain"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="mui_Payments" Header="Zahlungen" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25"  Padding="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="Payment"/>

            <MenuItem  Header="Diverses" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu_PopupRight}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25" Padding="5,0,0,0">
                <MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
                <MenuItem x:Name="mui_Products" Header="Produkte" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25" Padding="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="Products"  Margin="0,-4,0,0"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="mui_Recipients" Header="Empfänger" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25" Padding="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="Recipients"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="mui_Adjustments" Header="Adressfeld" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="25" Padding="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="Adjustments"/>
            </MenuItem>

        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding ViewModelTitle}" Margin="60,3,0,0 " Padding="6,2,6,4" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="{StaticResource Grey02}" Template="{DynamicResource DropShadowSubmenu}" IsEnabled="False" ></MenuItem>
    </Menu>


    <ScrollViewer  Margin="0,30,0,0" Background="{DynamicResource Grey09}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" Background="#FF06B836">

        </ContentControl>

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Looks like the view you're showing still has the old viewmodel. If you're creating a new instance of `NewViewModel` at all, you're probably just discarding it. Can we see all of the C# code which is expected to create a new instance of `NewViewModel`, assign it to `CurrentViewModel`, and all of the XAML which is expected to get the new value of `CurrentViewModel` into some `Content` or `DataContext` property somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added the code. I have checked the constructor of the viewmodel is being called.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint here: `CurrentViewModel = new CorrectInvoiceViewModel();` and confirmed that that is the line of code which is being called when you execute the command via the menu item?

Comment: Yes, gets a hit every time you click the menu. Left a trace in the constructor too, which confirms the constructor is called.

Comment: Hmmm. How are the properties of CorrectInvoiceViewModel initialized? Also, have you confirmed that `SetProperty` is raising PropertyChanged on "CurrentViewModel"? You could attach a handler to the viewmodel's own `PropertyChanged` to confirm that.

Comment: I am using a viewmodel base class that implements PropertyChanged in every setter: SetProperty(ref _CurrentLease, value);

Comment: I have attached a handler as you suggested: CurrentViewModel.PropertyChanged += test; and it is not bein called. This is strange, because if the PropertyChanged  event is not fired, wouldn't the view stop updating alltogether?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112079/discussion-between-user947737-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awaiting confirmation, but after some time in chat, it looks like the problem may be this bit in CorrectInvoiceView.xaml

```
<UserControl.DataContext> 
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="CorrectInvoiceViewModel_Resource"/> 
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Your `DataTemplate` for `CorrectInvoiceViewModel` is correctly instantiated when `CurrentViewModel` changes to a `CorrectInvoiceViewModel`. It's instantiated with the value of `CurrentViewModel` for a `DataContext`, and then it *replaces that DataContext with something else* -- a stored copy of that viewmodel, always the same stored copy, because it's defined as a resource somewhere.

So if you remove those three lines, I think you should see it behaving as expected.

Comment: The problem was solved thanks to @Ed Plunkett, who was kind enough to spend the necessary time to work it out!

Comment: For any with the same issue: it is still necessary to set the CurrentViewModel to NULL before re-assigning it.

Comment: @user947737 Any new value ought to do the job, I would think, but hey, it's working.